# VHDL downto incorrect MSB

Tags: vhdl

I have the following input signal:

```
addr : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0);
```

As far as I know, this means that addr(9) is the most significant bit.
But when run a simulation and assign, say, 128 to it, I get the following:

```
0(9) 0(8) 0(7) 0(6) 0(5) 0(4) 0(3) 1(2) 0(1) 0(0)
```

Meaning that the most significant bit is actually addr(0).

The assignment is done through simulation via vector waveform, in Quartus 9.1. I assign an arbitrary value to it.

Here is part of the .vhd file, where I use this:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

ENTITY ram_256x4B IS
PORT(clk, wr_en : IN STD_LOGIC; -- clock, write control signal
    addr : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0); -- read and write addresses
    d : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0); -- data to be written
    q : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0)); -- memory read output
END ram_256x4B;

ARCHITECTURE comportamental OF ram_256x4B IS

SIGNAL addr_validation_bits : STD_LOGIC;

BEGIN
addr_validation_bits <= addr(9) & addr(8);

END comportamental;
```

If the valued of `addr` is 2, I expect `addr(9)` and `addr(8)` to be both `0`, but instead they are `0` and `1`, respectively.

Comment: `9 downto 0` makes bit 0 the rightmost bit. If you consider the rightmost bit to be the most significant bit, then `9 downto 0` also makes bit 0 the MSB. If you want bit 9 to be the rightmost bit, use `0 to 9`.

Comment: I want the rightmost bit to be 0, but also the LSB. Say that I give the value 2 to this vector of bits, the result I want is 0000000010, where the leftmost bit is 9 and and the rightmost is 0.

Comment: How do you assign 128?

Comment: Show us the offending code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without knowing better the offending function(s), statement(s) or expression(s) would appear to have been authored by you? `0` is not a valid identifier in VHDL.

Comment: I added the full .vhd file code in the question, perhaps it can help.

Comment: The **full** code is not desired; please make a "**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example", since doing so will often yield the answer, and will greatly help other readers.

Comment: The value on "Addr" is assigned outside this VHDL module, in your testbench, which you haven't shown us. Which means you won't get a good answer. Best practice has the testbench also in VHDL, so that testbench and component agree on the meaning of each bit. Try it. Paebbels is hinting that if you're assigning 128 via some other means (like forcing signals) you'd better be sure that way works. (Incidentally I'd recommend making Addr Unsigned from numeric_std , it'll make life such as address arithmetic much easier)

Comment: Ok guys, I edited with some more info, and reduced the vhdl code to only the part where I use `addr`

Comment: Show the part where you *assign* `addr`.

Answer (score 1):

This assigns a STD_LOGIC_VECTOR with 128.

```
architecture ...
  signal addr : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
begin
  addr <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(128, addr'length));
end;
```

`addr(7)` is '1', all other bits are '0'.